# Isotope - Change corner stamp by filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

i am currently trying to rebuild the functionality from that website: http://etchapps.com/

On the homepage they show everything, and with the menu you can filter the output. The thing that i did not get working in a good way for now is the corner stamps.
On the "home", they have the corner stamps shown somewhere random in the grid and when you then change the filter of the page, they have a different corner stamp for each filter.
So what i am actually fighting with is to be able to change the corner stamp on a filter. I got this working implementing

```
$iso.isotope('destroy');
```

On my filter call, but this breaks the animation.

Any ideas?

Here is a fiddle that shows the issue with changing the corner stamp: https://jsfiddle.net/sgurlt/buwndhns/3/

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996005/jquery-isotope-corner-stamp-issue?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to destroy isotope before settings and initialize it again after setting done. Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buwndhns/7/).

```
$iso.isotope('destroy');

//Your personal settings goes here then

$iso.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element',
  sortBy : 'random',
   filter: filterElement
});
```

Comment: That did it :) should i first filter or first set the stamp when split this into 3 functions:  fn_init, fn_filter, fn_stamp?

Comment: sorry I don't know more about it. I think There is no difference in order of settings. Just remind to destroy it first. second: settings. third: Re-initialize